# How to center the Nav-Bar

Tags: html, css

Hy!

I don't know how to center the Nav-Bar please help!

HTML:

```
<html>
<script src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src='jquery.divslideshow-1.2-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

/*** 
    Simple jQuery Slideshow Script
    Released by Jon Raasch (jonraasch.com) under FreeBSD license: free to use or modify, not responsible for anything, etc.  Please link out to me if you like it :)
***/

function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    // uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

    // var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
    // var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
    // var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});

</script>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<body>

    <div id="page-wrap">
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="images/logo.png"/></td>
        <td>        <div id="slideshow">
            <img src="/images/trompete.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1" class="active" />
            <img src="/images/floete.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1" />
        </div></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="container"> 

    <ul id="minitabs"> 
    <li><a href="#" class="active">News</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#" >Fotos</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Mitglieder</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Jugend</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Gästebuch</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Intern</a></li> 
    </ul> 

    </div> 



        <br/>
        <div><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi</p>
        </div>
    </div> 

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Css:

```
#page-wrap { position: relative; width: 1024px;
            margin: 50px auto; padding: 20px; 
            background: white; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; 
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; -webkit-border-radius:30px;

            }

#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
     }
#nav li {
    float: left; }
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 56px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    }
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff; }

 p { font: 15px/2 Georgia, Serif; margin: 0 0 30p x 0; text-indent: 5px; }

#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:165px;   
}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    height:146px;
    width: 650px;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}

.container {
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 40px 0px 40px 0;
    background: #fff;
    }

#minitabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 40px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #587DC6;
    }

#minitabs li {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    }

#minitabs a:link, #minitabs a:visited {
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 10px 4px 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #C6C6C6;
    }

#minitabs a.active:link, #minitabs a.active:visited, #minitabs a:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #B80028;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #587DC6;
    }
```

Comment: Please trim you code down to only the parts relative to the navigation bar, or post a JSFiddle

Comment: Where is the #nav css style used, I do not see id="nav" anywhere in the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To centre your nav you will need to do the following:

**CSS:**

1. In `#minitabs` assign
   `text-align:center;`
2. In `#minitabs a:link, #minitabs a:visited` remove or comment out `float:left;`

That should centre your nav. You will have to adjust some of your styles in your nav to get it to look the same as before but at least it should be a starting point for you.

**See live link on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AvavN/**